# Set Created By field for Folder in Document Library

Tags: document-library, folder, metadata

I need to migrate documents from xml to Document Library. We can use Files.Add method to create documents with created by and modified by fields. How can we update / create Folders in Document Library with our custom created by and modified by fields??